# getting WebClient$RequestHeadersSpec.header(String, String[])" is null while mocking webclient in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-webclient

have created the springboot application and using webclient for calling the external API synchronously, have written testcases using junit 5 and mocked the webclinet using mockito. however API call is giving the below exception while running the testcase :

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersSpec.retrieve()" 
  because the return value of "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersSpec.header(String, String[])" is null
```

**Attaching the testcase :**

```
    @SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StrategyTest {
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec<?> requestHeadersUriMock;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> requestHeadersMock;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseMock;
    @MockBean
    @Qualifier("kwebclient")
    private WebClient kwebclient;
    @MockBean
    private AuthTokenManager authTokenManager;
    @MockBean
    private TokenRefreshScheduler tokenRefreshScheduler;


@Test
    void testOptimise1() {
        when(authTokenManager.getAuthToken()).thenReturn(authTokenResponse);
        prepareWebClientMock();
        CReady cReady = setTestCReady();
        Strategy.invokeGetScItem(LocationAPIUrl, lin, kwebclient, authTokenManager,
                tokenRefreshScheduler);
        assertNotNull(cReady);

    }

private void prepareWebClientMock() {
        doReturn(requestHeadersUriMock).when(kongWebclient).get();
                lenient().when(requestHeadersUriMock.uri(Mockito.any(Function.class))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);

        doReturn(requestHeadersMock).when(requestHeadersMock).accept(notNull());
        doReturn(requestHeadersMock).when(requestHeadersMock).header(notNull(), 
         notNull());
        doReturn(responseMock).when(requestHeadersMock).retrieve();
   doReturn(Mono.just(APIResponseJsonString)).when(responseMock).toEntity(String.class);
}
}
```

**Invoking API in the code :**

```
        Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> monoresponse = kWebclient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(finalurl).build())
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authTokenManager.getAuthToken().getAccessToken()).retrieve()
                    .toEntity(String.class);

            response = monoresponse.block();
```

**We are creating the Webclient with certificate to call external API as shown below :**

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("kWebclient")
    public WebClient createWebClient() throws Exception {

        return buildSslEnabledWebClient();

    }

    private WebClient buildSslEnabledWebClient() throws Exception {

        final KeyStore trustStore = createKeyStore(trustStorePath, 
         kConfigVault.getKTrustStorePassword());

        try {

            final TrustManagerFactory trustManager = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManager.init(trustStore);

            final SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(trustManager).build();

            final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(ssl -> {
                ssl.sslContext(sslContext);
            });
            final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
            final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size)).build();

            return WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(strategies)
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | SSLException e) {
            log.error("Could not initialize Webclient with the trustore data", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of mocking the `WebClient` run a mock web server and declare the behavior you want. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient. There’s not much point in testing  HTTP client code if you’re not making any calls.